# Json response not showing in div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hopefully someone can help me here, I am tired of banging my head on the desk. I am not sure why the json response isn't showing up on the div below the form. I can see the response in my firebug debugger(Firefox debugger), but nothing shows up in div.

I've the main `register.php` that contains the form and javascript and calls another `register.php` file with the php code that calls the registration function. I can create new account and data files to the database without any problem, but I am unable to get the response back in my div. Please help!

***register.php***

```
<body>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="form">
    <form id="register" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="small">
    <a href="?page=login">I already have an account</a><br/>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myForm = $('#register');

    myForm.validate({
            errorClass: "errormessage",
            onkeyup: false,
            errorClass: 'error',
            validClass: 'valid',
            rules: {
                email: { required: true, email: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 100 },
                username: { required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 30 },
                password: { required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 100 }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element)
            {
                var elem = $(element),
                    corners = ['right center', 'left center'],
                    flipIt = elem.parents('span.right').length > 0;

                if(!error.is(':empty')) {
                    elem.filter(':not(.valid)').qtip({
                        overwrite: false,
                        content: error,
                        position: {
                            my: corners[ flipIt ? 0 : 1 ],
                            at: corners[ flipIt ? 1 : 0 ],
                            viewport: $(window)
                        },
                        show: {
                            event: false,
                            ready: true
                        },
                        hide: false,
                        style: {
                            classes: 'ui-tooltip-red'
                        }
                    })
                    .qtip('option', 'content.text', error);
                }
                else { elem.qtip('destroy'); }
            },
            success: $.noop,
    })
});

$("#register").submit(function(event) {
    if($("#register").valid()) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        var $form = $( this ),
            mail = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),
            user = $form.find('input[name="username"]').val(),
            pass = $().crypt({method:"sha1",source:$().crypt({method:"sha1",source:$form.find('input[name="password"]').val()})});

        $.post("inc/action.php?a=register", {email: mail, username: user, password: pass},
            function(data) {

                    $("#message").html('<p> code: ' + data.error + '</p>');
                    $("#message").append('<p> message: ' + data.message + '</p>');

            }, "json"
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $("[id^=ui-tooltip-]").effect("pulsate", {times: 3}, 300);
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

***register.php***

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) { $email = $_POST['email']; } else { echo 1; exit(); }
if(isset($_POST['username'])) { $username = $_POST['username']; } else { echo 1; exit(); }
if(isset($_POST['password'])) { $password = $_POST['password']; } else { echo 1; exit(); }

$register = $auth->register($email, $username, $password);

$return = array();

switch($register['code'])
{
    case 0:
        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['message'] = "You are temporarily locked out of the system. Please try again in 30 minutes.";
        break;
    case 1:
        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['message'] = "Username / Password is invalid";
        break;
    case 2:
        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['message'] = "Email is already in use";
        break;
    case 3:
        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['message'] = "Username is already in use";
        break;
    case 4:
        $return['error'] = 0;
        $return['message'] = "Account created ! Activation email sent to " . $register['email'];
        break;
    default:
        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['message'] = "System error encountered";
        break;
}

$return = json_encode($return);

echo $return;
```

Comment: have you tried `alert('whatever')` in your success function body to verify it actually executes? For the records, this is a brute force way of doing it, you could also `console.log('whatever')` in the success function

Comment: just tried it didn't work. And I know it definitely executes because I can register new users and they show up in the database. I also see the confirmation in firebug.

Comment: what I mean is that your `function(data) {` does not execute (at least this is what your comment seems to indicate? you did not see the `alert()`?). What all this means that your ajax call may not **succeed**, or you would see the alert.

Comment: Please add console.log(data); exactly in the first line of your post success function and paste the result. And confirm if any error message shows up in console.

Comment: I'm guessing your request failed. Add some error handling to your $.post request like `$.post("[url]", {}, function(){alert("success")}).fail(function(data){ console.log(data) });` Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object) for more context on error handling with the $.post method.

Comment: result from console. `{"error":1,"message":"Email is already in use"}`

Comment: @jmaloney I actually have some if statement for in there, but I took it out to and replaced it with `$("#message").html('<p> code: ' + data.error + '</p>');` just to dump the result for testing.

Comment: Where does your output from console come from, success or fail?

Answer (score 0):

Add header('Content-Type: application/json') before returning the json-encoded data.

in json.php

```
<?php
$data['error']=1;
$data['msg']="error";

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

in index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url:'json.php',
        success:function(data){
            $('body').html(data.msg);
        }
    });
</script>
```